# Can you recommend a free API to get a list of regions and cities from a country?

Tags: gratis, api, geocoding

I need to populate some drop-down lists for an address form, so whenever a user selects a country, he should have a list of all regions (states/provinces or whatever official subdivision the country uses) to chose from and then all the localities from that region.

I'd be happy with a database too and I could implement my own API around it.

Comment: I have updated your question and expanded *region*, please add more info: what size of *localities* do you require?

Comment: Don't forget that you can get G.I.S help on our sister site http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: [OpenData.SE] is full of requests for [city data](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=cities)

Comment: I have reverted the previous edit. The original request was for a *(free)* API, which means 'free' is optional and paid solutions are also welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the data from, *or the [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) of,* the [Open Street Map](https://www.openstreetmap.org) project, *subject to applicable licences or conditions of use*, or from other Geographic Information Systems, ([GIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_information_system)), [data sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GIS_data_sources) of which there are a huge number.  You may wish to narrow down your range of countries if appropriate.